# mimic user sign in using only javascript, HTML, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html

so I am learning how to prototype website right now, and one of the requirement is to design and implement a paper prototype into an actual prototype on the web using ONLY javascript, HTML, and CSS.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to mimic the user log in function without using any databases. I'm thinking of maybe creating a method in the lines of

```
in javascript:
var username = Bob123
var password = BobHasNoPassword
```

and when I type that into the HTML form, it will redirect to another page.

Comment: You can do it easily but my question is why you want to save the credentials on client side?

Comment: This is for an assignment, and the assignment strictly limits the implementation to only Js, HTML, and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the HTML5 localStorage to store the username and the password. localStorage serves as a Storage API on your browser.Almost like a Database. When the user enters a username, you match it with the localStorage data using the getItem method to validate. You can even store multiple users by using multiple uniques key to store them. It can also serve for your session state and so on.

```
// Store values e.g register user
localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith");
localStorage.setItem("password", "p@55word");

// Retrieve user password/username
var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var username = localStorage.getItem("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if this is just for prototyping only, I would have a username and password stored in variables. When the login is submitted, check against those variables and redirect to proper prototype page if matching. I assume you will give the credentials to show how it works and let them try to use with and without right credentials. Just add conditional that will direct to correct page if variables match or direct to another page if they don't.